# Prestashop Product Import (CSV) - Delete products which ID's doesn't appear in the CSV

Tags: csv, import, prestashop, product

I am using **Prestashop 1.6.1.9** and I have close to **5000 products** in my site, which I have imported using the Prestashop **Import CSV** option, in Back end.

I have to update the CSV on a daily basis, to update the **price** and the **quantity**. The problem is that the supplier of the CSV doesn't put products with **0 quantity** in the CSV, they just delete them entirely, so I have no way of updating the products that have 0 stock, because they don't show up in the CSV.

Is there any way I can remove the products, when importing the CSV, so that the ID's that don't show up in the CSV get removed from the DB of my site?

Comment: I don't know why you decide to delete products why not to disabale them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do and script to accomplish what you want. There is no method on Prestashop to do that.

Another approach is to import CSV directly into a new temporary DB table. Then you could execute something like this query:

```
DELETE FROM ps_product WHERE id_product NOT IN (SELECT id_product FROM temporary_table)
```

Then remember to use `pscleaner` module to check integrity restrictions and clean up DB from old remain values.

Good luck.

Comment: Your solution was good, also I found another method: Compare the ID of the products that are already on my shop against the ID's of the newly imported CSV and find the ID's that do not match. Basically, the ID's that are on my SHOP and are not in the CSV need to be disabled.